# Is there a way to make the compiler pick a certain overload where its somewhat ambiguous?

Tags: c++, templates

I got this:

```
json& add(char* key, char* value) {
    s.append("\"").append(key).append("\":\"").append(value).append("\",");
    return *this;
}

json& add(char* key, const char* value) {
    s.append("\"").append(key).append("\":\"").append(value).append("\",");
    return *this;
}

template <typename vt>
json& add(char* key, vt value) {
    s.append("\"").append(key).append("\":").append(std::to_string(value)).append(",");
    return *this;
}
```

So 3 overloads for this function.

The first one is supposed to handle a char* value.

The last one is supposed to handle all the numeric types like uint_8t, int_8t, uint16_t .... float, double

if I use this function for example:

```
void test(json obj, char* value) {
    obj.add("test", value);
}
```

Then everything works alright with just the first and the last overload. If I try to do this however:

```
void test(json obj) {
    obj.add("test", "blah");
}
```

Then it will try to use the last overload (the one with the template) instead of the char* one since technically I'm passing a const char* to it.

So now I need to have the middle overload just for that.

Question is - is there a way to define a range of types for the template that its supposed to handle? To restrict vt to only the numeric types I mentioned? That should divert the compiler to use the char* overload instead and I wouldn't need the const char* one.

Comment: you mean you wouldn't need the `char*`one, right?

Comment: @KarstenKoop either works for my purposes

Comment: Cast one or more of the arguments to the type requried by the desired overload. NB There is no such thing as 'somewhat ambiguous': there is ambiguous and non-ambiguous.

Comment: Adding to the ambiguous/non-ambiguous comment, details are here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution under "Best viable function". Point 3 says that non-templates are preferred over templates, but in this case if you don't have the const char* overload then the template as taken as const char* to char is not a viable conversion.

Answer (score 3):

The non-const `char*` overload is not needed as you don't modify the parameter.
So the remaining ones are the second and the last version of you overload.

You stated that the templated overload is only meant for integral or floating point number types. I would recommend to use `std::enable_if_t<>` to restrict access to these types.

I would also recommend to make your key a `const char*`.

```
#include <string>

class json
{
private:
    std::string s;

public:
    json& add(const char* key, const char* value) {
        s.append("\"").append(key).append("\":\"").append(value).append("\",");
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename vt, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<vt>>>
    json& add(const char* key, vt value) {
        s.append("\"").append(key).append("\":").append(std::to_string(value)).append(",");
        return *this;
    }
};

int main(int, char**)
{
    json j; double d = 0.1245;
    j.add("Hello1", "World");
    j.add("Hello2", 1234);
    j.add("Hello3", 1234.1f);
    j.add("Hello4", d);
}
```

Comment: That's a solution to this specific test case but not the question. I also want to use the same overload for std::string and also template the key type so instead of having to write 15 overloads I could get away with just 3 for each function.

Comment: "To restrict vt to only the numeric types I mentioned?" My example just shows that.

Comment: unfortunately that part doesn't seem to work in a fashion that would help me, MSVC just says that x overloads have similar conversions and the conversion between const char* and char* as the value type only works implicitly if the template overload is removed.

Comment: Then maybe you should rephrase your question so it reflects what you want to know. My answer shows exactly how you can restrict the template as you asked and even shows that it works: https://godbolt.org/g/acXon8

Comment: Note: I just the `d` literal for the double value. gcc can handle this but MSVC can't. Just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it today is using enable_if and type traits. You want to define your template function as follows:

```
    template <typename vt, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<vt>>>
json& add(const char* key, vt value) {
    s.append("\"").append(key).append("\":").append(std::to_string(value)).append(",");
    return *this;
}
```

Note this part: `typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<vt>>>`

Hopefully in the next standard we will get concepts which will simplify this weird syntax.

If you are looking for more information, and background behind this technique, this is a very nice article: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/sfinae-and-enable_if/